# Angular 2 Security and An Observable

Tags: angular

As part of our security, we need to authenticate the user and then get the rights before we call the service getting the data.  How do I do a series of calls in Angular 2?  The plan is to make the security piece a separate class that would ensure the user is authenticated and cache the rights.

```js
@Injectable()
export class BankInfoService {
  private _bankInfoUrl = 'http://ourwebsite/api/GetAllClabeBankCodes';
  private _authenticateUrl = 'http://ourwebsite/api/AuthenticateUser';
  private _getRightsUrl = 'http://ourwebsite/api/GetRights';

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getBankInfos(): Observable<BankInfo[]> {

    this._http.get(this._authenticateUrl);

    rights = this._http.get(this._getRightsUrl);

    return this._http.post(this._bankInfoUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <BankInfo[]> response.json().BankCodes)
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  private handleError(error: Response) {
      console.error(error);
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `CanActivate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Caching the informations

Http calls are cold observables: they are re-created everytime you subscribe, what you need is to create a hot observable, that will keep emiting the last value. You can do this by using `publishReplay(n)` that will replay the last `n` emitted values, and then use `connect()` to start emitting. You can also use `refcount()`,that will keep emiting the value as long as there is a subscriber listening to the stream :

```js
export class AuthService {
  rights: Observable < Rights > ;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.rights = this.http.get('url')
      .map(response => new Rights(resp.json())) //transform http response to Rights object
      .publishReplay(1); //always replay the last value / transform to hot observable
    this.rights.connect();// start emitting
  }
```

Nice article on [hot and cold observables here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html).

### Chaining :

This is the most simple part, you can use the `switchMap()` operator:

> Maps each value to an Observable, then flattens all of these inner Observables using switch.

```js
export class BankInfoService {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  getBankInfos() {
    return this.authService.rights.flatMap(() => this._http.post(this._bankInfoUrl))
      .map((response: Response) => < BankInfo[] > response.json().BankCodes)
      .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  How would I call the Authenticate before the Get rights?

Comment: I guess you need to call it just once ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a AuthGuard that performs this AAA tasks. The Guard can use a service that cache the data using ReplaySubject. Here is an example how route, the service, guard and component can work together.

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Routes, RouterModule, Route} from '@angular/router';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
 RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AaaService {
  private subject = new ReplaySubject();

  constructor() {
    // replace  Observable.of to your http calls
    Observable.of('user')
      .switchMap(x => Observable.of(['delete', 'edit']))
      .catch(x => Observable.of([]))
      .subscribe(this.subject);
  }

  getRights() {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private aaaService: AaaService) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: 
      RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.aaaService.getRights()
      .map((rights: Array<string>) => {
        if (rights.length === 0) {
          this.router.navigate('/login');
        }
        return true;
      });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cpm',
  template: `
    <div>
      hi from component. Rights: {{rights | async | json}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent {
  rights;

  constructor(private aaaService: AaaService) {
    this.rights = aaaService.getRights();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <a routerLink="/mypath">go to auth path</a>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'mypath',
    component: MyComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [AaaService, AuthGuard],
  declarations: [App, MyComponent],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```